# Is there any PersistenceSpecification equivalent in EF?

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, fluent-nhibernate

Generally, my ORM is NHibernate. However, the next project I'll be working on must use Entity Framework. With NH, I tend to use [PersistenceSpecification](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Persistence-specification-testing) to check if my mappings are ok. Is there any EF equivalent?

Thanks.

Luis